# How can I check that a SQL statement executed without error in Ruby?

Tags: php, sql, ruby, sqlite

I'm re-writing some scripts from PHP to Ruby.

In PHP I can put the SQL statement in a variable and execute it and then check the variable to see if it executed without error.

For example `if ($query)`.

Documentation on SQL in Ruby is not as extensive as PHP.

How can I check that a SQL statement executed without error?

Thanks

Comment: try/catch is available in most programming languages.  Also, I disagree with the vote to close this question.

Comment: Are you executing raw SQL statements in Ruby? Are you using a framework like Rails or Sinatra?

Comment: I'm using raw SQL statements.

Comment: How are you connecting to the database and executing the query? Paste code, please.

Comment: Don't use raw SQL. Ruby has excellent ORMs that will help you in a number of ways, including determining whether you got an error. I'd recommend looking at [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/). Raw SQL becomes a porting and maintenance nightmare, whereas an ORM makes it almost transparent and effortless.